# Vector subscript out of range when incrementing an int?

Tags: c++, list, vector

So strange situation, I am creating a list of structs, and then I am trying to update one of the list members with new values, and then move it back into the list.

I seem to be able to copy the values of the struct at iterator just fine, but when I attempt to update the value of the struct's member (using int++;) it throws an exception in the vector class of all things.

Any kind of explanation as to what might be happening here would be helpful.

```
struct Blob
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

list<Blob> blob; 
// Add a Blob to blob using .push_back(); here 
for(list<Blob>::iterator iterator=blob.begin(); iterator!=blob.end(); ++iterator)
{
    Blob temp;
    temp.x = ((Blob)*iterator).x; 
    temp.y = ((Blob)*iterator).y; 
    if (temp.x < 10 - 1)
        temp.x++; /* Exception: vector: line 932 - "Vector subscript out of range"  */
    ((Rain)*iterator) = temp; 
}
```

Comment: Showing a complete testcase that compiles and exhibits the same behaviour would be much more useful than code snippets that are invalid on their own and do not contain any vector that this might be about.

Comment: What is the line `((Rain)*iterator) = temp;` supposed to do? What is `Rain` and why are you casting?

Comment: Why don't you just say `temp.x = iterator->x` ?  (That casting is not needed, although that isn't your issue)

Comment: Minus the `Rain` cast, this works fine: http://ideone.com/7I3xF

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update the existing value of object then take a reference of it. I have written a sample code to explain the same

```
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Test
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    list<Test> lTest;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        Test t1;
        t1.x = i;
        t1.y = i*i;
        lTest.push_back(t1);
    }

    list<Test>::iterator lIter = lTest.begin();
    for(;lIter != lTest.end();++lIter)
    {
        Test &t1 = *lIter;
        cout<<"1 Val is:"<<t1.x<<"|"<<t1.y<<endl;
        t1.x += 2;
        t1.y += 2;
        cout<<"2 Val is:"<<t1.x<<"|"<<t1.y<<endl;
    }

    lIter = lTest.begin();
    for(;lIter != lTest.end();++lIter)
    {
        Test t1 = *lIter;
        cout<<"3 Val is:"<<t1.x<<"|"<<t1.y<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother to take a reference?  What's wrong with `lIter->x += 2`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a loop it's likely there's another way to do it. You can use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Blob
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void incrementXIfLessThanNine(Blob& blob)
{
    if(blob.x < 9)
    {
        blob.x++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Blob> blobs;
    std::for_each(blob.begin(), blob.end(), incrementXIfLessThanNine);
    return 0;
}
```

If you're using C++11:

```
#include <list>

struct Blob
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<Blob> blobs;
    for(Blob& blob: blobs)
    {
        if(blob.x < 9)
        {
            blob.x++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```